# How to sticky div table header?

Tags: html, css

I am creating table with `div` tags instead of using `table`. Here is [***JsFiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/d0m5dqn9/1/) link. Now I got a problem that I can't sticky first row of table *(I define as tableHeader)*. Can somebody point me how to stick header of my table ?

I used as...

```
<div class="gridHeader" style="position: fixed; z-index: 1000; top: 0px; width: auto;">
```

but this goes outside of the table. Below is my **HTML**

```
<div id="grid">
            <div class="gridHeader">
                <div class="gridHeader gridCell"><label>#</label></div>
                    <div class="gridCell"><label>01</label></div>
                    <div class="gridCell"><label>02</label></div>
                    <div class="gridCell"><label>03</label></div>
                    <div class="gridCell"><label>04</label></div>
                    <div class="gridCell"><label>05</label></div>
                    <div class="gridCell"><label>06</label></div>
                    <div class="gridCell"><label>07</label></div>
                    <div class="gridCell"><label>08</label></div>
                    <div class="gridCell"><label>09</label></div>
                    <div class="gridCell"><label>10</label></div>
                    <div class="gridCell"><label>11</label></div>
                    <div class="gridCell"><label>12</label></div>
                    <div class="gridCell"><label>13</label></div>
                    <div class="gridCell"><label>14</label></div>
                    <div class="gridCell"><label>15</label></div>
            </div>
                <div class="gridRow">
                    <div class="gridHeader gridCell"><label>Room #01</label></div>
                        <div class="gridCell item"></div>
                        <div class="gridCell item"></div>
                        <div class="gridCell item"></div>
                        <div class="gridCell item"></div>
                        <div class="gridCell item"></div>
                        <div class="gridCell item"></div>
                        <div class="gridCell item"></div>
                        <div class="gridCell item"></div>
                        <div class="gridCell item"></div>
                        <div class="gridCell item"></div>
                        <div class="gridCell item"></div>
                        <div class="gridCell item"></div>
                        <div class="gridCell item"></div>
                        <div class="gridCell item"></div>
                        <div class="gridCell item"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="gridRow">
                    <div class="gridHeader gridCell"><label>Room #02</label></div>
                        <div class="gridCell item"></div>
                        <div class="gridCell item"></div>
                        <div class="gridCell item"></div>
                        <div class="gridCell item"></div>
                        <div class="gridCell item"></div>
                        <div class="gridCell item"></div>
                        <div class="gridCell item"></div>
                        <div class="gridCell item"></div>
                        <div class="gridCell item"></div>
                        <div class="gridCell item"></div>
                        <div class="gridCell item"></div>
                        <div class="gridCell item"></div>
                        <div class="gridCell item"></div>
                        <div class="gridCell item"></div>
                        <div class="gridCell item"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="gridRow">
                    <div class="gridHeader gridCell"><label>Room #03</label></div>
                        <div class="gridCell item"></div>
                        <div class="gridCell item"></div>
                        <div class="gridCell item"></div>
                        <div class="gridCell item"></div>
                        <div class="gridCell item"></div>
                        <div class="gridCell item"></div>
                        <div class="gridCell item"></div>
                        <div class="gridCell item"></div>
                        <div class="gridCell item"></div>
                        <div class="gridCell item"></div>
                        <div class="gridCell item"></div>
                        <div class="gridCell item"></div>
                        <div class="gridCell item"></div>
                        <div class="gridCell item"></div>
                        <div class="gridCell item"></div>
                </div>
        </div>
```

and **CSS** as ....

```
        #grid {
        display : inline-block;
        color: white;
        /* box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff inset; */
        border-collapse: collapse;
        font-size: 90%;
        overflow-y: auto;
        height: 130px;
    }
    .gridHeader {
        display:table-header-group;
        width: 100px;
        font-weight:bold;
        text-align: center;
        /* text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7); */
        background: #618aa0; /* Old browsers */
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #618aa0 0%, #091544 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
        background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#618aa0), color-stop(100%,#091544)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #618aa0 0%,#091544 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
        background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #618aa0 0%,#091544 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
        background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #618aa0 0%,#091544 100%); /* IE10+ */
        background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #618aa0 0%,#091544 100%); /* W3C */
        filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#618aa0', endColorstr='#091544',GradientType=0 ); 
    }

    .gridRow {
        display:table-row;
    }
    .gridCell {
        display:table-cell;
        border : 1px solid black;
        overflow: hidden;
        padding: 4px 10px;
    }

    .item {
        cursor: crosshair;
    }

    .selected {
        background-color: #3E6640;
        border: 0 solid #3E6640;
    }
```

Comment: have you tried this  https://www.datatables.net/ ?

Comment: @DesignSnippet.com No , sir .. I need to create my table with simple HTML and Css. I can't use other libs or js. Thanks sir.

Comment: what's wrong with `<table>` ?

Comment: @DaveSnyder my above code snippets are dynamically generated from my **(Java Server Faces)** pages and it's not convineint with `table` tag.

Comment: Unless I've misunderstood, is absolute positioning not sufficient?

Comment: @Kwarrtz I haven't too much experience on *CSS*. I googled how to sticky 'div' and they showed me to use as `position:fixed;top:0`.

Comment: @Cataclysm: Yes, that should work.

Comment: Can you edit your script to make a change in final HTML code or you're only able to change CSS?

Comment: @Kwarrtz  yes , yes bro... I can't stick my first row with this but layout of other rows are ugly. I have no idea how to fix it.

Comment: @Kwarrtz  yes bro I can change but I can't used `table` tag.

Comment: [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/dPixie/byB9d/3/light/) is a JSFiddle demonstrating roughly what I think you want.

Comment: @Kwarrtz yes this is as I want but it uses `table` tags instead of `div` s.

Comment: It shouldn't matter. `table` tags are really just `div`s with `display: table-*`  built in.